# Ruby version differs from the rbenv one in server

Tags: 16.04, ruby, rails

In my server (Ubuntu 16.04) I have two users: `root` and `other`. I want to config a Rails project.

Now, after some configuration I installed the `v2.5` version of Ruby (required) as a `root` user using Rbenv, but in the `other` profile the version kept the same as default (`v2.3`).

I've managed to set the proper version in the `other` profile. When I do:

```
rbenv versions
```

The output is the following:

> system
>
> * 2.5.0 (set by /home/other/.rbenv/version)

But when I do:

```
ruby -v
```

The version keeps being the default one:

> ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

How to set the version to `v2.5`?

Answer (score 1):

just run it:

```
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Change zshrc to bashrc if don't use zsh.